# How to fix the webdriver config so the test result won't be differ between computers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I write the test on  Mac and everything works well.

Then I migrated the `test script` to server's (ubuntu on Linode) docker container.

The test was failed,

> @driver.current_url will show me https://m.flyscoot.com/

but actually I gave the url  `http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/` to open.

My test was failed by unexpectedly redirected to  `https://m.flyscoot.com/`

I've no idea why this happened?

I guess the web driver was be thought a mobile version browser.

How could I cheat the website so that I can get the identical test result ?

> Test failed environment is running on `selenium/node-firefox-debug` and `selenium/hub` from this repo `https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium`

## Dockerfile

```
  FROM selenium/node-firefox-debug
  ....
  CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"]
```

## docker-compose

```
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/crawler
    ports:
      - 5900:5900
    links:
      - hub:hub
```

## entry_point.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash
  # RUN THE CRON JOB
  export GEOMETRY="$SCREEN_WIDTH""x""$SCREEN_HEIGHT""x""$SCREEN_DEPTH"

  xvfb-run --server-args="$DISPLAY -screen 0 $GEOMETRY -ac +extension RANDR" \
      java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar \
      -role node \
      -hub http://$HUB_1_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR:$HUB_1_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT/grid/register \
      -browser browserName=firefox
      --background
```

Comment: What is the website criteria for redirecting to mobile? Detecting certain user agents or certain screen sizes?

Comment: actually I have no idea, i tried to change the drivers screen resolution, but it didn't work

Comment: I'll go a step further and say that your website is probably incorrectly detecting a "mobile" browser when there is not one.  I use docker-selenium for automated testing and it functions exactly as it would on a normal desktop.

Comment: Hi is it possible cause by Ubuntu OS ? i think your docker environment is different from mine, pls see update . thank you so much